# Angular : Weird data hierarchy when using promises

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that retrieves data using promise :

```
...
return {
   getData : getData
}

function getData(aParam) {
    $http.get('test.json').then(function (response) {
          return response.data;
    });
}
...
```

In my controller, where the service is injected, I can call my method like this :

```
...
var myData = MyService.getData('foobar');
...
```

The service is called but when I inspect the `myData` content, I have to access it like this :

```
myData.$$state.value.foobarArray
```

Question : Is it possible to avoid the `$$state.value` part ?

Regards.

Comment: Your service doesn't return anything, so myData is undefined. If your service actually does `return $http.get(...)`, then what is returned is a promise. You're supposed to access its future value using `myData.then(function(value) {...});`

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this as just a comment if I had enough pointz, but try adding return before $http.get.

Answer (score 0):

Your service exposes an async function so it either needs to return a promise..

```
function getData(aParam) {
    return $http.get('test.json');
}
```

...and resolve the promise in the controller.

```
MyService.getData('foobar').then(function(data){
    var myData = data;
});
```

Or use a callback function...

```
function getData(aParam, callback) {
    $http.get('test.json').then(function (response) {
          callback(response.data);
    });
}
```

... passed in from the controller.

```
 MyService.getData('foobar', function(data){
     var myData = data;
 });
```

I cant explain the 'weird hierachy' off the top of my head but this should get you headed in the right direction.